# Select all of django foreign key model if condition or part if another condition

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following models:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    project_collaborators = models.ManyToManyField(User)
...

class Node(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    collaborators = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
```

What I want to do is select all projects where a user is a project_collaborator, as well as all nodes associated with that project, and also select all projects where a user is a collaborator on a node within a project, but in each project only select the nodes that the user is a collaborator of.

A user may be a project_collaborator as well as a collaborator on a node, but this should only return one instance of the project/node.

The closest I've gotten so far is `Project.objects.filter(Q(node__collaborators=user) | Q(project_collaborators=user)).distinct()`, but that doesn't quite do what I'd like it to.

EDIT: Solution I used

I started with this in views.py to get all the projects the user would be associated with:

```
projects = Project.objects.select_related().filter(Q(project_collaborators=request.user) | Q(canvas__collaborators=request.user)).distinct()
```

Then in the template I did:

```
{% for project in projects %}

    {{ project.title }}
    <ul>
    {% for node in project.node_set.all %}

        {% if request.user in project.project_collaborators.all or request.user in node.collaborators.all %}

            <li>{{ node.title }}</li>

        {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <br />

{% endfor %}
```

This allows me to print out all nodes if the user is a project collaborator, or only the specific nodes if they are only a node collaborator, while still printing out all projects which they are associated with.

Comment: Do you want Project or Node? because if in the second situation you just want Node`s that user is a collaborator! we`ll have to retrive a list of notes instead of projects! Otherwise if we retrive the Project it will retrive all notes! not just the ones that the user have access!

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to do all of that in a single ORM call. I would start by creating individual statements that select the data that you need, then look at ways of combining those statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll give you two approaches:

**Doing this with as few queries as possible**

Get the `Node` objects and then use them to get the `Project` objects, rather than the other way around:

```
nodes = Node.objects.filter(Q(project__project_collaborators=user) | Q(collaborators=user)).select_related('project').distinct()
```

Now you have just the nodes you want, and only the nodes you want. What you do have is multiple representations of the project. If you only actually need the nodes, this isn't a problem. If you need to make a list of projects, you can use Python to compile this easily enough, although not as a `QuerySet`:

```
projects = []
for node in nodes:
    if node.project not in projects:
        projects.append(node.project)
```

If you need projects as a `QuerySet`, you can get them with one additional query -- here's the code for that (in lieu of the block above):

```
project_ids = set([node.project.id for node in nodes])
projects = Project.objects.filter(id__in=project_ids)
```

Note that you'd have to reassociate the `Project` instances with their appropriate `Node` instances if you need that association:

```
projects_and_nodes = {}
for project in projects:
     projects_and_nodes[project] = [node for node in nodes if node.project == project]
```

**Doing this in as clean code as possible**

You already seem to know how to get the `Project` instances you want -- the piece that you haven't quite gotten right is getting the correct `Node` instances. You need some logic once you're retrieved the `Project` that says:

```
# pseudocode
if the user is a collaborator on this project:
    get all the nodes
else:
    get only the nodes applicable to the user
```

In this scenario, use the code you provided to get the projects, and then here's the Python for getting the appropriate nodes:

```
if request.user in project.project_collaborators.all():
    nodes = project.node_set.all()
else:
    nodes = project.node_set.filter(collaborators=request.user)
```

Hope that helps. :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I ended up doing a little combination of what you suggested as well as what I already had. I'll edit the first post with what I did.